# Adapting navigation derictive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, navigation

Hej,
I am looking for a method to change the navigation links in the navigation bar according to whether a user is logged in or not. Obviously, a logged in user should be able to navigate to more pages.

I programmed a UserService which wraps the ng-token-auth module (https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) and adds a boolean variable holding the login state. The service looks similar to this:

```
angular.module('app')
  .run(function($rootScope, $location, userService) {
    $rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', function(ev, user) {
      userService.setLoggedIn(true);
      $location.path('/on/dashboard');
    });
  })  
  .factory('userService', function($auth) {
    var service = {};
    service.loggedIn = false;

    service.submitLogin = submitLogin;
    service.setLoggedIn = setLoggedIn;
    service.getLoggedIn = getLoggedIn;

    return service;

    function submitLogin(params) {
      $auth.submitLogin(params)
    }
    function setLoggedIn(bool) {
      service.loggedIn = bool;
    }
    function getLoggedIn() {
      return service.loggedIn;
    }
  });
```

My directive looked like this:

```
.directive('agNavigation', function(userService) {
    if(userService.getLoggedIn()){
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/views/userNavigation.html'
      }
    }else{
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/views/navigation.html'
      }
    }
  });
```

When logged in, the view changes to the dashboard but the directive does not update, which is logical because the directive isn't called again. Now, I am trying to use the `$watch` function but I cannot figure it out. See here:

```
.directive('agNavigation', function(userService) {
    var navUrl = '';
    if(userService.getLoggedIn()){
      navUrl = '/views/userNavigation.html';
    }else{
      navUrl = '/views/navigation.html';
    }
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: navUrl,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        scope.$watch(function() {
          return userService.getLoggedIn();
        }), function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if(newValue){
            navUrl = '/views/userNavigation.html';
          }else{
            navUrl = '/views/navigation.html';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

I am very new to AngularJS, thus I am very happy for any advice, or if I am approaching this in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`userService.getLoggedIn()` will fails in compile time of directiveas you write the code in your first example code. You should have really need to move that code to the `templateUrl` function & return the URL on basis of condition.

**Code**

```
.directive('agNavigation', function(userService) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: function(){
           if(userService.getLoggedIn()){
             return '/views/userNavigation.html';
           }
            return '/views/navigation.html';
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: thank you, that makes sense but it does not change the fact that the directive is loaded and the /views/navigation.html is rendered, and then after login the directive does not react to the change of userService.getLoggedIn()